# if current_user.id = @game.user_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, if-statement, relation

I have links to the show pages for each game in my project and if the
games user_id matches the id of the currently signed in user then I want
it to display the edit button if they are not then it shouldn't display.

I currently have the following code set but it doesn't work. Every game
has the edit button display. The code is as followed:

```
 <% if current_user.id = @game.user_id %>
    <div id="text3"><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_game_path(@game) %></div><br />
 <% end %>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MrDanA's answer is most probably the error, but you may want to make this code better. Checking like that is not the Rails way of doing it. Instead, make a User instance method like :

```
def has_game?(game)
  self.games.exists?(:id => game.id)
end
```

and then in your view :

```
<% if current_user.has_game?(@game) %> ...
```

(can even be better by further delegating exists into the game model, as a scope or so, if you like)

Comment: Assuming that such checks will happen often and with different models, I would go one step further and consider using CanTango (https://github.com/kristianmandrup/cantango/wikin). Thus the permissions are captured in one module, and do not crosscut the whole model.

Comment: that's taking it too far. You are assuming that he needs authorization.

Comment: That's right and there are hints that he will do. So if he will eventually find himself writing this permission-statements for three or more models he can have a look at cantango. :)

Comment: i don't see any hints about roles or authorization, but ok :P

Answer (score 1):

You want `==`

So:

```
<% if current_user.id == @game.user_id %>
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I have done so but now it doesn't display it at all, even for those games that belong to the currently logged in user.

Comment: how do you define @game in your controller ?