# current_user.id == @game.user_id not being recognized

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, edit

I have the following code in my games_controller edit section:

```
def edit
   @game = Game.find_by_game_name(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    if current_user.id == @game.user_id
      format.html 
    else
      format.html { redirect_to games_path, notice: 'You are not authorized to change these details.'}
    end
  end
end
```

My problem is that if I click on the edit feature even for those games who do belong to a user I goes to the else line with the notice saying I am not authorized to change these details. The user_id field of the games matches with the id of the user but it won't let me edit. Any ideas why this might be?

Comment: Please use better titles for your questions.

Comment: Is `current_user.id` returning a string or an integer? Same question, but for `@game.user_id`.

Comment: integer. for example the current_user.id is 32 and the user_id in the game field is 32.

Comment: Add `raise "#{current_user.id} | #{@game.user_id}" | #{current_user.id == @game.user_id}` before your condition and see what's going on. But you shouldn't handle permissions like that anyways. User cancan ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have pretty much asked the same thing as can be seen in this :

[if current_user.id = @game.user_id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9541761/if-current-user-id-game-user-id/9541830#9541830)

It will work if you do it this way.

In your current example, it probably does not work because you are not properly authorized. Try removing the if and see if it works at all without it.

Comment: Hi, I already have that code from the previous post in my application so that is not the problem. I removed the if statement surround it and that works fine, I can edit it bu if I was to go on to a game that does not belong to the current_user and just type the words edit in the top bar after its name then I can get in to the edit features. How would I prevent this?

Comment: Use the method has_game?(game) that i specify in the post i linked to. Check like : 'redirect_to error_page if not current_user.has_game(@game)'.

Comment: would that go in the following then:   def has_game?(game)
     self.games.exists?(:id => game.id)
  end so that it would be like if self.games.exist? else error message?

Comment: the method should go in your model, and then in your controller you should execute 'current_user.has_game?(@game) else error'.

Comment: Aah cheers for that, I had the previous code but had not put it in the controller. silly me. Thanks for your help.